# Why rpm is not working on cygwin terminal?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install some `RPM`s, and I am executing:

```
$ rpm --ignoreos -ivh *.rpm
-bash: rpm: command not found"
```

My main purpose is to install `tinyos-1.x` on Windows7 premium, for which I referred to this [page](http://wsn.cse.wustl.edu/index.php?title=TinyOS_1.x_Installation_on_Windows_XP). Any hints?

Comment: I suggest you install Ubuntu with oracle virtualbox and the follow this guide to install tinyos 

http://www.eetutorials.com/article/28/TinyOS-installation-guide-on-Ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the cygwin setup.exe and get to the select packages stage, type rpm into the text box and you should find only 'util' remains in the list, open the list of packages inside util and click on the 'new' column in the 'rpm' row, so you see a version number. Then carry on clicking next and the cygwin setup should install the package and all dependencies. You may need to quit the cygwin terminal and open it again, the rpm command should now be in your path.